# Scraping a table from a website using rvest

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape the table from the treasury website.

https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldYear&year=2019

What I have currently is to collect the data but

```
library("rvest")
url <- "https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll"

data <- url %>%
  html()
```

But I cannot seem to get it into a table format since I have a function.

```
data %>%
html_table()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to first use CSS to locate the node which contains the table. The table is big(around 7400 rows). It took 30 seconds to render using `html_table`.

```r
library("rvest")
library(httr)
url <- "https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll"
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"

data <- html_session(url,user_agent(ua))
data %>%
    html_node("table.t-chart") %>%
    html_table()
```